# Why doesn't Kotlin compile listOf to ImmutableCollections.ListN?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to use Kotlin alongside Java and but Kotlin's listOf method is immutable only in Kotlin. Whenever I use the codebase in Java I get an ArrayList instead of Java11's ImmutableCollections.ListN, which is actually immutable.
So I was wondering why Kotlin uses ArrayLists internally instead of ImmutableCollections.ListN and is there a way to overwrite this?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `ImmutableCollections` is not a part of the public API, so we can't represent a list in the code as `ImmutableCollections.ListN`. Java doesn't support read-only or immutable collections in its type system as Kotlin does, in Java read-only/immutability is implementation details.

Comment: @broot While true, I think the OP is more wondering why `listOf(...)` doesn't compile to `List.of(...)` when targeting the JVM/Android.

Comment: @Slaw My impression is that OP suggested `ImmutableCollections.ListN` is somehow "more immutable" than Kotlin's implementation ("Kotlin's listOf method is immutable only in Kotlin", "ImmutableCollections.ListN, which is actually immutable"). But they're pretty much the same - they are both represented as just `List` and throw when being modified. "Kotlin's listOf method is immutable only in Kotlin" - the same can be said about `ImmutableCollections`. They are seen as immutable only in the stdlib internally while initializing them, but anywhere else they are "mutable".

Comment: @broot The problem the OP has, from what I understand, comes from passing a Kotlin `List` to a Java API. In Kotlin, the `List` interface has no mutator methods. Pass it to Java, however, and it sees a `java.util.List`, which does have mutator methods. The OP would, if I'm not mistaken, like an `UnsupportedOperationException` to be thrown in the scenario where the Java API attempts to modify the list by calling those mutator methods.

Comment: @Slaw And this is exactly what happens right now. Lists created with `listOf()` are immutable, meaning they throw UOE on modification. I think OP's point is that from the Java code it is not possible to distinguish read-only and mutable list, but this is because Java doesn't have a concept of read-only lists. And the problem is the same no matter if we use immutable lists created in Kotlin or we don't at all use any Kotlin code and we create immutable list with e.g. `List.of()`. We just can't do this from Java. Well, let's wait for OP ;-)

Comment: @broot Maybe you're right. I'm not as familiar with all the intricacies of Kotlin. However, the OP said, "_Whenever I use the codebase in Java I get an ArrayList_". So, if the OP is right and `listOf(arguments...)` is creating a `java.util.ArrayList` under the hood, then I don't see how UOEs would be thrown upon modification. That implementation is not immutable.

Comment: There are some mentions on YouTrack, e.g. [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-9959/listOf-mapOf-setOf-should-return-collections-with-a-consistent-mutability#focus=Comments-27-2829635.0-0) mentioning support for null elements as a possible blocker

Comment: Ok, I just realized I wasn't right about `listOf()` being fully immutable. It throws UOE for operations changing its size, so add, insert, remove, but set is still allowed.

Comment: @broot @Slaw Ok, yeah I'm getting UOEs when trying to add elements to it. 
I was expecting it would just be a normal ArrayList since
`println(listOf(1,2,3)::class.qualifiedName)` prints out `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`

Comment: @funazol The `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` and `java.util.ArrayList` classes are different implementations of `List`. The former is what's returned by the `Arrays.asList(T...)` method, and it is a **fixed-size** list. In other words, you cannot add or remove elements to or from the list, but you can replace elements (with the `set` method). Any method which would result in the size changing will throw a UOE; but still, the list is not truly immutable.

Answer (score 0):

I have traced it down and indeed the implementation chosen from Kotlin looks strange.

1. [ListOf(elements)](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/f3385fbdcb8b9dc29661a8a4973c855cdcf73767/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Collections.kt#L77) will call `elements.asList()`
2. which will land [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/f3385fbdcb8b9dc29661a8a4973c855cdcf73767/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/generated/_ArraysJvm.kt#L132) as the varargs input will be an array of objects.
3. Then as you could see [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/collections/ArraysUtilJVM.java) which is the last part it ends up invoking `Arrays.asList(array)` from `java.util.Arrays`.

Keep in mind that the `Arrays.asList()` produces an `ArrayList` from the class `java.util.Arrays.class` which is a different class from the normal `ArrayList` which exists in `java.util.ArrayList.class`.

Independent of this, still the chosen class from Kotlin from `java.util.Arrays.class -> nested class ArrayList` is not a fully immutable list. It is a list with fixed size as it is directly backed by an array, meaning you could not modify the length of the list by adding more elements but you can modify the existing elements inside.